nvim, nvchad, mason, lazy trying to add a remote plugin
i am trying to install "numirias/semshi" on nvim, im using mason as a plugin manager. it was added like this inside plugins.lua:
local plugins = {
    {
        "williamboman/mason.nvim",
        opts = {
            ensure_installed = {
                "pyright",
                "numirias/semshi",
            }
        },
    },

when running :MasonInstallAll
i get an error saying package is not found however pyright is installed and working properly. any help is appreciated

Return that object... don't assign it to a variable., and make sure it's in the proper location so Lazy can find it.

i do have the return plugins statement below.. so your saying to not use mason but instead load through lazy? or does mason use lazy, gotta be honest here i dont know any Lua and followed a tutorial with a bunch of custom lua.. so if there is a way to use the existing structure i think would be best.. which is mason.. again perhaps im completley off here

Mason is a UI for installing things for LSP, with some other plugins, things like DAP. You can install those too with Lazy if you want, but sometimes they require a bit more configuration and might be best installed manually if not using Mason, but for other plugins you can't use Mason. I think you're confusing the job that Mason does with what Lazy or other plugin managers do. Definitely install Lazy, and use that for other plugins, but maybe use Mason for pyright specifically since that's in Mason's domain. I'll include my Lazy setup below.

Lazy is a full plugin manager that handles all sorts of plugins for neovim. There's not really a plugin that Lazy can't handle with the right configuration. Mason on the other hand deals specifically with LSP (Language Server Protocol). LSP handles things that deal with the language you're working with directly... things like syntax highlighting, being able to select things based on code structure, linting and so on. Pyright falls into that domain, and there are other plugins that can extend Mason to make it capable of handling debug adapters and a few other specific categories. To run Mason, just use :Mason to open the UI, and then select the plugins you want from there to install them with Mason. For Lazy, try something like this:
-- <Path to your nvim config>/lazy/init.lua
local m = {}

m.checkExists = function()
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)
end

m.init = function()
require("lazy").setup("lazy.plugins", {
    dev = {
        -- directory where you store your local plugin projects
        path = "~/plugins",
        fallback = false,
    },
  git = {
    -- defaults for the `Lazy log` command
    -- log = { "-10" }, -- show the last 10 commits
    log = { "-8" }, -- show commits from the last 3 days
    timeout = 600, -- kill processes that take more than 10 minutes
    url_format = "https://github.com/%s.git",
    -- lazy.nvim requires git >=2.19.0. If you really want to use lazy with an older version,
    -- then set the below to false. This should work, but is NOT supported and will
    -- increase downloads a lot.
    filter = true,
  },
    ui = {
        icons = {
            cmd = "⌘",
            config = "",
            event = "",
            ft = "",
            init = "⚙",
            keys = "",
            plugin = "",
            runtime = "",
            source = "",
            start = "",
            task = "",
        },
    },
})
end


return m

-- <Path to your nvim config>/lazy/plugins/lsp.lua
-- You can have as many files as you want in this plugins directory. 
-- Obviously use the plugins that you want here. This is from my config; follow this same structure, but modify the plugins to fit your needs.
return {
    {
        "VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim",
        branch = "v1.x",
        dependencies = {
            { "neovim/nvim-lspconfig" },
            { "uga-rosa/cmp-dictionary" },
            {
                "williamboman/mason.nvim",
                config = function()
                    require("pluginInit.mason")
                end,
            },
            { "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim" },
            { "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp" },
            { "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp" },
            { "hrsh7th/cmp-buffer" },
            { "hrsh7th/cmp-path" },
            { "saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip" },
            -- WARNING: cmp-nvim-lua seems to be causing issues in nvim config files for now. Reinstall if the issue can be easily resolved when back on wifi.
            --
            { "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lua" },
            { "hrsh7th/cmp-cmdline" },
            { "b0o/SchemaStore.nvim" },
            { "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip" },
        },
        config = function()
            -- require("pluginInit.lsp")
            require("oldfaithful.lsp")
        end,
    },
    {
        "jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("pluginInit.null_ls")
        end,
        dependencies = {
            "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
        },
    },
    {
        "ray-x/lsp_signature.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("pluginInit.lsp_signature")
        end,
    },
    {
        "nvimdev/lspsaga.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("lspsagaConfig")
        end,
        dependencies = {
            "nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons",
            "nvim-lspconfig",
            "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
        },
    },
    {
        "numToStr/Comment.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("pluginInit.comment")
        end,
    },
    {
        "folke/todo-comments.nvim",
        dependencies = "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("pluginInit.todo_comment")
        end,
        opts = {
            keywords = require("utils.todoComments"),
        },
    },
    {
        "folke/trouble.nvim",
        dependencies = "nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons",
        config = function()
            require("pluginInit.trouble")
        end,
    },
    {
        "windwp/nvim-autopairs",
        config = function()
            require("nvim-autopairs").setup({})
        end,
    },
    {
        "kylechui/nvim-surround",
        config = function()
            require("nvim-surround").setup({})
        end,
    },
    { "windwp/nvim-ts-autotag", ft = { "typescript", "typescriptreact" } },
    {
        "JoosepAlviste/nvim-ts-context-commentstring",
        ft = { "typescript", "typescriptreact" },
    },
    {
        "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip",
        version = "v2.*", -- Replace <CurrentMajor> by the latest released major (first number of latest release)
        build = "make install_jsregexp",
        config = function()
            require("pluginInit.luasnip")
        end,
    },
}

And then call the setup function from your <Path to nvim config>/init.lua file like:
require("lazy.init").checkExists()
require("lazy.init").init()


ok let me give this a shot see what i can get going here.. thanks for your help, ill post back in a bit

yeah i think im gonna just stick with vim and vim plug,. ive literally spent my entire morning looking into this,,, anyways i appreciate the help but ill have to take this on over the weekend

No worries. Any plugin manager can do mostly what Lazy does. Lazy is just really good at... you know... lazy loading. The main thing to take away is that Mason can't handle all of your plugins, that's the job of Lazy or vim plug, but for LSP stuff Mason provides a super useful UI and installs them automatically in a way that sometimes plugin managers can't accomplish without extra work on your end. Just don't include LSP stuff in your plugin manager config (pyright) if you plan to install it with Mason (which you should). Good luck.
